# PHP finish text with ... if it is too long

Tags: php

I have got div with width of 300 and i have also got children span in it text of which doesn't depend on me.If span's text is

'WWWWWWWWWW'

It should stop after five `W`,but if text is

'llllllllll'
It should stop after 10 `l`'s

Comment: I'd recomend you to have a look at this jquery pugin http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Comment: Please edit your question to show us what you have tried in order to get the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to apply any PHP programming logic here.

This thing can be achieved in CSS easily.

```
.text-ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

And add this class to your span:

```
<span class="text-ellipsis">WWWWWWWWWWWWW</span>
```